# Schematron check for unique values among multiple elements

Tags: xml, schematron

I need to check that `siteId` contains unique record id's throughout the document. For example: site 11111 submits record with id 1 & 2 and 3 & 4. site 2222 submits records 3 & 4.

GOOD:

```
<submission>
<site>
<siteId>11111</siteId>
<record><id>1</id></record>
<record><id>2</id></record>
</site>
<site>
<siteId>2222</siteId>
<record><id>3</id></record>
<record><id>4</id></record>
</site>
<site>
<siteId>1111</siteId>
<record><id>3</id></record>
<record><id>4</id></record>
</site>
</submission>
```

BAD:

```
<submission>
<site>
<siteId>11111</siteId>
<record><id>1</id></record>
<record><id>2</id></record>
</site>
<site>
<siteId>2222</siteId>
<record><id>3</id></record>
<record><id>4</id></record>
</site>
<site>
<siteId>1111</siteId>
<record><id>3</id></record>
<record><id>4</id></record>
<record><id>4</id></record>
</site>
</submission>
```

Answer (score 0):

The test pattern using count() and disting-values() taking from here: http://xml-buddy.com/xmltribune/?p=274 should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by below code:-

```
 <iso:pattern id="site">
   <iso:rule context="id">
       <iso:assert test="count(id) != count(distinct-values(ancestor::site/record/id))">BAD</iso:assert>
   </iso:rule>
</iso:pattern>
```